# How can I get the iPad bubbles wallpaper (since it no longer shows up as an available wallpaper after changing from it)?

Tags: ipad

How can I get the iPad bubbles wallpaper? It no longer shows up as an available wallpaper after changing from it.

Answer (score 2):

I pulled the "bubbles" wallpaper from an old file cache of mine.

[image]